# Are eigenvalues of $A^{T}A$ positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a matrix $A$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ is it true that $A^{T}A$ has only positive eigenvalues?

Could anyone suggest me how to show it?

The situation is

$(A^{T}A) \vec{x}= \lambda \vec{x}$

But I really can't see why $\lambda>0$

Thanks in advice for your help

Comment: they are non-negative

Comment: Hint: What is the fundamental property combining transpose and dot (inner) product?

Comment: If $A$ is not invertible, then $0$ is an eigenvalue, contradicting your claim.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know that $tr(A^{T}A)>0$ in Euclidean spaces but does this prove that all the eigenvalues are positive?

Comment: @FrancescoCaruso: When $A=0$ then the trace of $A^TA$ is not $>0$.

Comment: See the answer. He gave it away. $Ax\cdot y = x\cdot A^\top y$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple calculation shows:
$ \langle \lambda \vec{x}, \vec{x} \rangle = \langle A^{T}A \vec{x}, \vec{x}\rangle = \langle A \vec{x}, A \vec{x} \rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not very used to this notation so I did not actually understand why you considered the subspace $\mathscr{L}(\lambda \vec{x},\vec{x})$ (if this is what you did)

Comment: Notation $\langle \vec{x}, \vec{y} \rangle$ is actually a simple dot product not a subspace. When talking about real vectors it is equal to $\vec{x}^T \vec{y}$ (if they were complex vectors then it is equal to $\vec{x}^* \vec{y}$) with usual matrix multiplication.

Comment: (hopefully) easy properties of dot product that were used here: 1) $\langle \vec{x}, \vec{x} \rangle \geq 0$, 2) $\langle A^T \vec{x}, \vec{y} \rangle = \langle \vec{x}, A \vec{y} \rangle$ 3) $\langle \lambda \vec{x}, \vec{y} \rangle = \lambda \langle \vec{x}, \vec{y} \rangle $. Note that when over complex field these are slightly different.

Comment: Ok that's all clear now! Thanks again!